# How can I open the underlying script of built-in functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I open the underlying script for built-in functions? For example the function `len`.

I want to open the script of the `len` function to study how the underlying code is built, for educational purposes.

I have tried writing `open(len)` and `open(len())`, but I only get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/someo/PycharmProjects/Test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
open(len())
TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These definitions can't be accessed, because they aren't part of a package. They live in Python itself, therefore they cannot be accessed. You can't get in by making them raise an error either (`len(5)` won't let you see inside the function, and will just raise a `TypeError`). Python itself won't show you the full traceback because these definitions aren't meant to be seen.

Comment: If you broke into Python's source, you wouldn't find Python, but instead C. These basic functions are as low as Python goes.